# Jquery Ajax with GET not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this peace of HTML code

```
<select id="country" name="country" onchange="updateState()">
    <option value="1">Country 1</option>
    <option value="2">Country 2</option>
    <option value="3">Country 3</option>
</select>
<select id="state" name="state">
    <option value="1">State 1</option>
    <option value="2">State 2</option>
    <option value="3">State 3</option>
</select>
```

and im trying to update state select with JQuery ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateState(){
    var state = $('#country').val();
    alert(state);
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "../functions/selectstate.php",
        data: { sta : state }
    }).done(function( html )
    {
            $('#state').empty();
            $('#state').append(html);

    })
    }
}
</script>
```

selectstate.php have this php code, i tested it and work fine

```
include_once('select.php');
include_once('cndb.php');
$sDB = new SelectDb();
$data = $sDB->selectStatesById($_GET['sta']);
foreach($data as $row)
{
    echo "<option value=" . $row->state . ">" . $row->name . "</option>";
}
```

I just can't see where is the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: try removing the .. before the url

Comment: check your browser console to see the error. is it giving a 404

Comment: Observe the HTTP traffic using the browser's tools (e.g. F12 in IE or Chrome).  See what happens when that URL is requested.

Comment: i get this error in the console 'Uncaught ReferenceError: updateState is not defined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="1">Country 1</option>
    <option value="2">Country 2</option>
    <option value="3">Country 3</option>
</select>
<select id="state" name="state">
    <option value="1">State 1</option>
    <option value="2">State 2</option>
    <option value="3">State 3</option>
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change','#country',function (){
        var state = $('#country').val();
        alert(state);
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "../functions/selectstate.php",
            data: { sta : state }
        }).done(function( html )
        {
            //$('#state').empty();
            //$('#state').append(html);
            $('#state').html(html);
            // you can use it insetead of the above two lines
        })
        //}<-- here is th problem remove this extra bracket
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below approach. It might help
**HTML Code:**

```
<select id="country" name="country" onchange="updateState()">
<option value="1">Country 1</option>
<option value="2">Country 2</option>
<option value="3">Country 3</option>
</select>
<div id="stateDiv">
   <select id="state" name="state">
   <option value="1">State 1</option>
   <option value="2">State 2</option>
   <option value="3">State 3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
...
...
.done(function( result )
 {
   $('#stateDiv').html(result);
})
...
...
```

**PHP Code:**

```
...
...
echo '<select id="state" name="state">';
foreach($data as $row)
{
 echo "<option value=" . $row->state . ">" . $row->name . "</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
...
...
```